# Video as background with crop box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-video

I'm using [jCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) to define a crop area for a video element. I want the part of the video defined by the crop area to fill a container that has the same proportions as the crop area, but I'm having trouble with the math.

Video and crop area dimensions vary and the elements resize responsively, so I need to calculate position based on the coordinates.

I'm using CSS `transform:scale()` to enlarge the video and positioning it to show the crop area by using CSS `transform:translate()`.

Here's a diagram of what I want:

[image]

Below, I've simulated the video (green) and the crop area (red). When the proportions of the video and the crop area are the same, it works. Click the "zoom" button to zoom into the crop area.

```js
let $container = $('#container');
let $videoWrap = $('#videoWrap');
let $videoSrc = $('#videoSrc');
let $videoCrop = $('#videoCrop');

let videoWidth = 1280;
let videoHeight = 720;

let cropArea = {
  'x': 500,
  'y': 80,
  'w': 640,
  'h': 360
};

$container.css({
  'padding-bottom': (cropArea.h / cropArea.w) * 100 + '%'
});

$videoSrc.css({
  'padding-bottom': videoHeight / videoWidth * 100 + '%'
});

$videoCrop.css({
  'width': (cropArea.w / videoWidth) * 100 + '%',
  'height': (cropArea.h / videoHeight) * 100 + '%',
  'left': (cropArea.x / videoWidth) * 100 + '%',
  'top': (cropArea.y / videoHeight) * 100 + '%'
});


let scale = videoWidth / cropArea.w;
let tx = 0 - (cropArea.x / videoWidth * 100);
let ty = 0 - (cropArea.y / videoHeight * 100);

let css = {
  'transform-origin': '0 0',
  'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ') translate(' + tx + '%,' + ty + '%)'
};

$('#zoom').on('click', function() {
  $videoWrap.css(css);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 5px solid blue;
}

#videoWrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  transition: all 1s;
}

#videoSrc {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: green;
}

#videoCrop {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#zoom {
  margin: 2em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="videoWrap">
    <div id="videoSrc">
      <div id="videoCrop"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="zoom">Zoom</button>
```

But when the crop area has different dimensions from the video, the video is padded (like letterbox), which offsets the zooming.

```js
let $container = $('#container');
let $videoWrap = $('#videoWrap');
let $videoSrc = $('#videoSrc');
let $videoCrop = $('#videoCrop');

let videoWidth = 1280;
let videoHeight = 720;

let cropArea = {
  'x': 500,
  'y': 80,
  'w': 440,
  'h': 500
};

$container.css({
  'padding-bottom': (cropArea.h / cropArea.w) * 100 + '%'
});

$videoSrc.css({
  'padding-bottom': videoHeight / videoWidth * 100 + '%'
});

$videoCrop.css({
  'width': (cropArea.w / videoWidth) * 100 + '%',
  'height': (cropArea.h / videoHeight) * 100 + '%',
  'left': (cropArea.x / videoWidth) * 100 + '%',
  'top': (cropArea.y / videoHeight) * 100 + '%'
});


let scale = videoWidth / cropArea.w;
let tx = 0 - (cropArea.x / videoWidth * 100);
let ty = 0 - (cropArea.y / videoHeight * 100);

let css = {
  'transform-origin': '0 0',
  'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ') translate(' + tx + '%,' + ty + '%)'
};

$('#zoom').on('click', function() {
  $videoWrap.css(css);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 5px solid blue;
}

#videoWrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  transition: all 1s;
}

#videoSrc {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: green;
}

#videoCrop {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#zoom {
  margin: 2em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="videoWrap">
    <div id="videoSrc">
      <div id="videoCrop"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="zoom">Zoom</button>
```

I tried to calculate the amount that the video is padded and add it to the translate CSS to move the video up, but I must not be calculating it correctly.

```js
let $container = $('#container');
let $videoWrap = $('#videoWrap');
let $videoSrc = $('#videoSrc');
let $videoCrop = $('#videoCrop');

let videoWidth = 1280;
let videoHeight = 720;

let cropArea = {
  'x': 500,
  'y': 80,
  'w': 440,
  'h': 500
};

$container.css({
  'padding-bottom': (cropArea.h / cropArea.w) * 100 + '%'
});

$videoSrc.css({
  'padding-bottom': videoHeight / videoWidth * 100 + '%'
});

$videoCrop.css({
  'width': (cropArea.w / videoWidth) * 100 + '%',
  'height': (cropArea.h / videoHeight) * 100 + '%',
  'left': (cropArea.x / videoWidth) * 100 + '%',
  'top': (cropArea.y / videoHeight) * 100 + '%'
});


let scale = videoWidth / cropArea.w;
let tx = 0 - (cropArea.x / videoWidth * 100);
let ty = 0 - (cropArea.y / videoHeight * 100);

let offsetY = ((cropArea.h / cropArea.w) - (videoHeight / videoWidth)) / 2 * 100;

ty -= offsetY;

let css = {
  'transform-origin': '0 0',
  'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ') translate(' + tx + '%,' + ty + '%)'
};

$('#zoom').on('click', function() {
  $videoWrap.css(css);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 5px solid blue;
}

#videoWrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  transition: all 1s;
}

#videoSrc {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: green;
}

#videoCrop {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#zoom {
  margin: 2em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="videoWrap">
    <div id="videoSrc">
      <div id="videoCrop"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="zoom">Zoom</button>
```

What's going wrong?
I assume I'm overlooking something with the calculation or with the way percentages work.
I'm definitely open to suggestions if there's a different way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple alignment issue, 
change your `top:50%` to `top:59%`

```
#videoSrc {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 59%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: How did you calculate 59%? The sizes of videos and crop areas vary, so it needs to be calculated from those dimensions.

Comment: i didn't, you just needed to test and see. As your cropped box isn't places exactly at the 50% point.

Comment: That's true. The crop box can have any coordinates inside the video's dimensions. I need to calculate the position of the video based on its dimensions and the coordinates of the crop box.